# CKBuilder is not including some plugins that I choose

Tags: ckeditor

I go to CKEditor Builder and customize it´s full version adding some plugins, specifically (Upload Image, Image Browser and Auto Save)
FileBrowser is supposed to be a preset addon.

When i click to build it, it generates a zip file.

Looking into this zipfile i can´t see some of the correspondent folders inside plugin folder, like: "imagebrowser", "uploadimage".

Even the "filebrowser" that is a preset plugin for this version and "widget", "popup", "lineutils" and some of other necessary folder aren´t there.
PS: The "autosave" plugin installs correctly.

Whats going on? Does anyone knows whats wrong? I´ve tried other plugins combinations to check if the folders are included. I´ve restarted the computer, cleared browser cache, changed computers...nothing worked :(

I need Filebrowser, UploadImage e ImageBrowser.

If I install it manually it seens to work. But i´m having some troubles trying to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

CKBuilder takes the plugins that you request and tries to merge all the plugin.js files to improve performance, so it's normal that you don't see many folders in the zip.